# sql urlencoding function

Tags: php, sql, urlencode

Can anyone help me rewrite this ms sql function into PHP as a preg_replace()?
It's a urlencoding function, but l need to recreate it exactly for a migration project and am having troulbe understanding what it's doing.

```
USE [botw]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[UrlEncode]    Script Date: 9/24/2020 12:38:25 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[UrlEncode](@str as varchar(4000))
returns varchar(4000)
as
begin
declare @hex char(16)
declare @c char(1)
set @hex='0123456789ABCDEF'
declare @ostr varchar(4000)
set @ostr=''
declare @l int
set @l = 1
while @l <= len(@str)
begin
set @c = substring(@str,@l,1)
if ascii(@c) between ascii('0') and ascii('9')
or ascii(@c) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
or ascii(@c) between ascii('a') and ascii('z')
or @c = '/'
set @ostr = @ostr + @c
else if @c = ' '
set @ostr = @ostr + '_'
else
set @ostr = @ostr + '%' +
substring(@hex,(ascii(@c)/16)+1,1)
+substring(@hex,(ascii(@c)&15)+1,1)
set @l=@l+1
end
return @ostr
end
```

Comment: Please provide us code you have tried so far and specify where exactly is a problem.

Comment: So you actually want us to explain the SQL, or write the PHP?

Comment: is it doing what built in [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) does (with str_replace(' ', '_'))? can you show some example strings

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
Am l correct in assuming that this is what the sql function is doing:

1.) replacing spaces with _
2.) running a similar function to php's rawurlencode() on any character that is not A-Z, a-z, 0-9, / or _  Is my understanding of what's happening here correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but there are slight differences between this and `rawurlencode` which will not encode _Unreserved Characters_ (`-_.~`) but your function will.

Comment: @waterloomatt, thank you so much for our response. So are -_.~ the only unreserved characters that rawurlencode() in php doesn't hit? Like l said, l need to recreate this code's behavior exactly in php.

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php#refsect1-function.rawurlencode-returnvalues, yes, but read the RFC to make sure.